# Magento 2 product list widget, randomize

Tags: magento2, product-list, widget

How can I change the sort order of the product list widget to random()?
I am talking about the Product list widget you can insert on CMS pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This widget don't have sort functionality. You need create plugin.

You can find how on another topic:

[Magento 2 - catalog product list widget product order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127221/magento-2-catalog-product-list-widget-product-order)

Comment: yes I know I need to write some code, but I can not understand how to do.
    \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList::createCollection seems like a good start.

How can I there add so it is sort by random? (I know I should never edit to M2 source)