# Magento 2 Sort product in cms page widget block

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, sorting, widget

I want to insert multiple products in a cms page using SKU . So i did using blocks . So please see my code

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`sku`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`ab-54, ab-12, abc-45, ab-76, abs-09`^]^]"}}
```

Now the products are showing in the frontend .

But here the problem is the products are not showing based on this order `ab-54, ab-12, abc-45, ab-76, abs-09` . Actually i want to show the product exact this order .

***Currently sorting based on ascending order of id  . see this is the order of ids that i getting for the products in front end 342, 526, 638 , 672, 1109***

But i need to display product as per the given sku order .

Please help

Comment: can you please tell me currently which sequence products are showing.

Comment: i think it is sorting based on id ascending order .  see this is the order of ids that i getting for the products in front end 342, 526, 638 , 672, 1109

Comment: possible to write sku name

Comment: there is no SKY NAME parameter in conditions drop down .

Comment: what is this - ab-54, ab-12, abc-45, ab-76, abs-09  ?

Comment: that is skus . ab-54 is sku of a product , ab-12 is sku of another products . They are sample sku . So please don't give importance to ab

Comment: You can review this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127221/magento-2-catalog-product-list-widget-product-order