# Change order of widget catalog products list

Tags: product, catalog, sorting, sort, list

I have a product in my product list, which must be at the top. After I have extended the product list, the product is unfortunately no longer at the top. 
I add the product list via the widget catalog products list. 
I thought that you could use the category sorting way for this. The product which should be at the top I have given the position 1 and the other products higher numbers. Therefore I set "Catalog -> Category" to "All Store Views" and used the following display settings:

[image]

Then I did a reindex, cleaned the cache (with rm -rf /var/cache/* and bin/magento cache:flush) and deployed it again. The order does not change, even if I change the Display Settings to e.g. "Product Name". Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it myself. I thought the sorting point was in the backend. Apparently the widget can't be sorted by itself. That's why I used the plugin from Rian. However, it needs to be reworked, with Stefan's advice.
Here is the link from Rian's plugin: 
https://github.com/rianorie/magento2-sortcatalogwidget

and here the link from Stefan to improve it: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299908/86418

I hope that this will help somebody someday!